# How to capture mouseover of an individual bar/datapoint in an ASP.Net Chart Control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, charts

I have a single series bar chart created programmatically in codebehind which I would like to display the Y point value (somewhere above the bar, or maybe as a tooltip) when the user hovers their mouse over a bar.

Is there a native onmouseover event for the bars of the chart, or is it something that should be added through series.MapAreaAttributes?

Thanks!

Edit

After some experimenting I've found the points.tooltip attribute which I can add at the same time I add the point which will do what I want it to do, but it would still be nice to know if you can capture events for the bars, just for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Show all series' values in stacked bars mouseover (ASP.NET CHART)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2536993/show-all-series-values-in-stacked-bars-mouseover-asp-net-chart)

```
series.MapAreaAttributes = "onmouseover=""showTooltip('#VALY');"""
```

Where your showTooltip function would do as you required.

Comment: Thanks Justin, that also does the trick. Can that onmouseover attribute be used to do other things like switch css classes and the like?

Comment: Yeah, you can do basically anything you like with it by calling custom javascript, not sure how many of the parameters from 

http://support2.dundas.com/Default.aspx?article=1132

made it into the Microsoft version of the charting class